# In GSM is it correct to say A8 uses the random generated by the Auc and Ki to generate Kc?

Tags: gsm

In GSM is it correct to say the AuC uses A8 algorithm with as input a nonce and Ki to generate Kc used for encryption communication between the subscriber and base station? If not how is Kc forwarded to the mobile subscriber in a secure way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referenced [presentation](http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Studies/T-79.514/slides/S5.Brumley-comp128.pdf) describes how the protocol works.

The A3 algorithm is used for authentication and A8 for key derivation. They both take as input:

- A random 128 bits number challenge
- `Ki` a 128 bits private key (included in the SIM and known by the network)

A3 outputs a 32 bits response. And A8 a 64 bits `Kc` cipher key that will be used for A5 algorithm.

As both inputs can be known to the base station and the subscriber's device, there is no need to forward `Kc` to anyone. It's computed on the spot.